# How to bring Google Chrome settings to Windows 10?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, sync

I just noticed that all my Google Chrome settings are not synced with my Google Chrome in Windows 10. No addons, no bookmarks, no passwords, ... I am using Google Chrome smoothly in my Chromebooks, Macs and Linuxes, but not now with Windows 10. I logged into my Google Account in Google Chrome of Windows 10, but it does not bring the features.

How can you sync your Google Chrome settings with Google Chrome in Windows 10?

Comment: Log into the Google account your syncing with the other devices

Comment: @Ramhound It does not work.